A tough geometry problem: finding an interior point maximizing distances to vertices.
"In an equilateral triangle ABC, a point P lies inside the triangle such that the distances from P to the vertices A, B, and C are a, b, and c units, respectively. If  $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 25$  and the sum of the squares of the sides of the triangle is 49.
1)Find the possible values of the side length of the equilateral triangle.

Additionally, determine the location of point P such that the product of the distances a, b, and c is maximized."

My Attempt:
First of all I thought that this is a easy question as I solved the first part of the question very easily
It's simple
To find the possible values of the side length of the equilateral triangle, we'll use the given information and apply some geometry principles.
We know that in an equilateral triangle, all sides are equal. Let's denote the side length of the equilateral triangle as ( s ).
Given that  $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 25$, we have:
$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3s^2 = 25$
$s^2 = \frac{25}{3}$
Now, we're also given that the sum of the squares of the sides of the triangle is 49:
$s^2 + s^2 + s^2 = 3s^2 = 49$
From this, we can solve for  s :
$3s^2 = 49$
$s^2 = \frac{49}{3}$
Taking the square root of both sides:
$s = \sqrt{\frac{49}{3}}$
Which further simplifies to $\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{3}$
Thus, this is the possible value of the side length of the equilateral triangle.
But as I solved the first question effortlessly and moved to the second question I was stumped I had no idea how I can solve the second part of the question I tried to think a lot of ways in which I can solve it but nothing seems to work and I have no idea how can I move further

Since the product $abc$ is zero at A, B and C, would the product not be maximised at the centroid of the triangle?

I don’t understand your solution of the first part, at all. Why is $a^2+b^2+c^2=3s^2$? You get $s^2=25/3$ and then just ignore that altogether and find $s^2=49/3$. Actually, you don’t need to use $a^2+b^2+c^2=25$ in the first part at all.

@RedFive Does $a^2+b^2+c^2=25$ hold for the centroid though?

@Aig - maybe not. I've just drawn a sketch because, like you, I'm doubtful about the answer given to the first part and want to check for myself. It may well be correct, but I need to see for myself.

@RedFive Actually, all these points $P$ form a circle with center at the centroid of the triangle and radius $\sqrt{26}/3$.

This circle intersects with the sides of the triangle, and the product $abc$ is maximized at this intersection (following that $P$ is inside the triangle) and is approximately $9.5$ there.

There is a bit more to this question than I first thought. Some nice generalisations may be possible. The side length question, that is simple enough, but the rest... a few different approaches might work (aside from the algebra-bash)

This is solved using the AM-GM inequality:
We solve for the general case when the length of the triangle side is x
The area of the triangle can be presented in two ways
$$\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}x^2 $$
which after some calculation implies:
$$a+b+c = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x$$
by the AM-GM inequality:
$$\frac{(a+b+c)}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{abc}$$
which after calculation implies:
$$abc\geq\frac{\sqrt{3}}{72}x^3$$
equality holds when $a=b=c$, which is only possible when P is the centroid of ABC
